# Getting JVM ERROR 517 File-system corrupt in Blackberry Simulator

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

When I am running PhoneGap BlackBerry WebWork application using Eclipse Blackberry JDE 6.0 i am getting  an

```
JVM Error 517 FileSystem Corrupt.
```

but when i am running my normal Blackberry Application Is works fine in the same eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Try cleaning the simulator and also delete all the .dmp files from the simulators folder

Comment: Thnks for your rply.i have deleted all .dmp files but still error occures.

Comment: Hi Sagar, did you restart your simulator after deleting the .dmp files. You could also try deleting the .cod. .csl and .debug files and restart the eclipse. It might help.  As I Understand, 517 JVM error is an inconsistency which has been detected in the JVM persistent object store.

Comment: actually a problem is when i am running normal BB app.in simulator it works fine.but when i am running phonegap Webworks App,it gives me an error.

Comment: I have deleted all files as u told me to delete. but still error is ocurring.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I got my simulator to work again. On the simulator when you get this error scroll from "Reset" to "Delete modules" and click the track button. There are 4 different delete options, I chose all of them. Restarted the simulator and it started working again.